# playwright `Property 'get' does not exist on type 'APIRequest'

Tags: typescript, request, get, playwright

So the following code works for me in test.spec.ts:

```
//@ts-check
import { test, request } from '@playwright/test'

test('api test - to see if Playwright API calls are working', async ({ request }) => {
  const response = await request.get(`https://catfact.ninja/fact`);
  const statusCode = response.status()
  const responseBody = JSON.parse(await response.text())
)}
```

So I want to extract this call in a separate module.  I tried in separate file:

```
import { request } from '@playwright/test';

export async function getCatInfo() {
    const response = await request.get(`https://catfact.ninja/fact`)
}
```

I get an Error in VS Code: `Property 'get' does not exist on type 'APIRequest'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should import from `playwright/test`:

```
import { test, request } from '@playwright/test';

export async function getCatInfo() {
    const response = await request.get(`https://catfact.ninja/fact`)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out (and I feel stupid for being sloppy), but even when I correct that (like I did above),  I'm getting the error:
Property 'get' does not exist on type 'APIRequest'
    How are we supposed to use the get as outlined on https://playwright.dev/docs/api-testing ?